# How to push critical/emergency alerts/notifications on Android with Expo

Tags: android, expo

This question is the Android equivalent to this one:
[How to make critical alerts in ios with expo sdk 42 managed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69358515/7012917)

I already have iOS critical notifications configured:

```
await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync({
  ios: {
    allowAlert: true,
    allowBadge: true,
    allowCriticalAlerts: true,
    allowSound: true,
  },
})
```

But now I want to configure critical notifications for Android as well. I've googled and I've read the docs https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/, but I can't seem to find how it's done in Expo?

And I know it should be possible because my Huawei has an "Allow interruptions" permission that apps can set to "Receive notifications even when Do Not Disturb is enabled".

---

I'm using Expo SDK 49, React 18.2.0, and React Native 0.72.5